# Generator of complex-valued functions vanishing at infinity

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ be the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of continuous complex-valued functions vanishing at infinity, with involution given by $f^{\ast}(x) = \overline{f(x)}$. How can I prove that this commutative $C^{\ast}$-algebra is generated by the resolvent functions $f_{\pm}(x) = (i \pm x)^{-1}$?

Comment: Maybe I finally understood the answer: the solution is given by the complex version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem applied to the subsets $S_{\pm} := \{(i \pm x)^{-1}\}$ of $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$, which tells us that the polynomials in those functions are dense in $C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you noted in a comment, this is a consequence of the complex version of the Stone–Weierstrass theorem.  The hypotheses are easily checked.