# Certain resolvent functions generate $C_0(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I have two questions about the following passage taken from Higson-Roe's *Analytic K-Homology*:

[image]

1) What does "$T$ graded-commutes with $(i\pm D)^{-1}$" mean? In particular, what grading is being placed on the bounded operators on $H$?

2) In what sense do "$(i\pm x)^{-1}$ generate the $C^*$-algebra $C_0(\mathbb{R})$"?

Thanks!

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937901/generator-of-complex-valued-functions-vanishing-at-infinity. Somehow this didn't turn up on google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $T$ and $D$ as described,
$$
       TD=-DT \\
       T(\lambda I+D) =  (\lambda I-D)T  \\
       (\lambda I-D)^{-1}T = T(\lambda I+D)^{-1} \\
       ((\lambda I-D)^{-1}-(\overline{\lambda}I-D)^{-1})T=T((\lambda I+D)^{-1}-(\overline{\lambda}I+D)^{-1}).
$$
If $\varphi$ is a bounded Borel function on $\mathbb{R}$, then the above leads to
$$
        \varphi(D)T=T\varphi(-D).
$$
This is because
\begin{align}
     \mbox{s-}\lim_{v\downarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{a}^{b}\varphi(u)\{&((u-iv)I-D)^{-1} \\
    -&((u+iv)I-D)^{-1}\}du  \\
   = &(\chi \varphi)(D)
\end{align}
where $\chi$ is $1$ on $(a,b)$, is $1/2$ at $a$, $b$, and is $0$ otherwise, which follows from properties of the Poisson integral.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking about your answer at the moment. Do you know what might be meant by $(i+x)^{-1}$ and $(i-x)^{-1}$ generating $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ (I'm not sure, maybe Stone-Weierstrass is involved?)?

Comment: @ougoah : You can expand the resolvent $(\lambda-x)^{-1}$ about $\lambda=i$ to obtain the resolvent values for $|\lambda-i| < 1$ as a series in powers of $(i-x)^{-1}$. Then you can expand the resolvent about any of those points and eventually show that every $(\lambda-x)^{-1}$ for $\lambda$ in the upper half-plane is in the algebra generated by $(x-i)^{-1}$. Then you can do the same in the lower half-plane. With that, you can generate the full functional calculus $f(x)$ for continuous functions as I indicated in my post.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can I ask, is $\{((u-iv) - z)^{-1} - ((u+iv) - z)^{-1}\}$ the same as the Poisson kernel $Re\frac{\zeta+z}{\zeta-z}$?

Comment: The Poisson kernel in the upper half-plane is much nicer: $P(t,x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{(t-x)^2+y^2}$, which comes from $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\frac{1}{t-z}-\frac{1}{t-\overline{z}}\right)$, and is closely tied to the resolvent.

Comment: Sorry to ask one more question: what is $s-\lim$?

Comment: @oughoah : Limit in the strong operator topology. My use of it was confusing here because I already had a vector in the expression. Apologies for the confusing notation that way. I'm removing the $x$ now.